# Quitar Salto de Linea en un Textarea php mysql javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

tengo este problema, que al ingresar texto con salto de linea al textarea de mi campo Descripción producto se queda igual como la imagen siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, cuando le doy grabar o guardar de esta manera con salto de linea al mostrar en mi datatable no lo muestra por que est en "json", lo que necesito es que al ingresar el texto se coloque el texto de corrido o sin salto de linea.

Este es mi código para guardar o insertar:

```
if($datos["selActivarOferta"] == "oferta"){

    $datosProducto = array(
           "titulo"=>$datos["tituloProducto"],
           "idCategoria"=>$datos["categoria"],
           "idSubCategoria"=>$datos["subCategoria"],
           "tipo"=>$datos["tipo"],
           "detalles"=>$datos["detalles"],
           "multimedia"=>$datos["multimedia"],
           "ruta"=>$datos["rutaProducto"],
           "estado"=> 1,
           "titular"=> substr($datos["descripcionProducto"], 0, 225)."...",
           "descripcion"=> $datos["descripcionProducto"],
           "palabrasClaves"=> $datos["pClavesProducto"],
           "precio"=> $datos["precio"],
           "peso"=> $datos["peso"],
           "entrega"=> $datos["entrega"],  
           "imgPortada"=>substr($rutaPortada,3),
           "imgFotoPrincipal"=>substr($rutaFotoPrincipal,3),
           "oferta"=>1,
           "precioOferta"=>$datos["precioOferta"],
           "descuentoOferta"=>$datos["descuentoOferta"],
           "imgOferta"=>substr($rutaOferta,3),
           "finOferta"=>$datos["finOferta"]
       );


}else{

    $datosProducto = array(
           "titulo"=>$datos["tituloProducto"],
           "idCategoria"=>$datos["categoria"],
           "idSubCategoria"=>$datos["subCategoria"],
           "tipo"=>$datos["tipo"],
           "detalles"=>$datos["detalles"],
           "multimedia"=>$datos["multimedia"],
           "ruta"=>$datos["rutaProducto"],
           "estado"=> 1,
           "titular"=> substr($datos["descripcionProducto"], 0, 225)."...",
           "descripcion"=> $datos["descripcionProducto"],
           "palabrasClaves"=> $datos["pClavesProducto"],
           "precio"=> $datos["precio"],
           "peso"=> $datos["peso"],
           "entrega"=> $datos["entrega"],  
           "imgPortada"=>substr($rutaPortada,3),
           "imgFotoPrincipal"=>substr($rutaFotoPrincipal,3),
           "oferta"=>0,
           "precioOferta"=>0,
           "descuentoOferta"=>0,
           "imgOferta"=>"",
           "finOferta"=>""
       );

}
```

Este es el codigo Html:

```
   <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>


      <textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control input-lg descripcionProducto" placeholder="Ingresar descripción producto"></textarea>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Este es mi Datatable para lista Datos Json:

```
$datosJson .='[

                "'.($i+1).'",
                "'.$productos[$i]["titulo"].'",
                "'.$categoria.'",
                "'.$subcategoria.'",
                "'.$productos[$i]["ruta"].'",
                "'.$estado.'",
                "'.$productos[$i]["tipo"].'",
                "'.$cabeceras["descripcion"].'",
                "'.$cabeceras["palabrasClaves"].'",
                "'.$imagenPortada.'",
                "'.$imagenPrincipal.'",
                "'.$vistaMultimedia.'",
                "'.$vistaDetalles.'",
                "'.$precio.'",
                "'.$productos[$i]["peso"].' kg",
                "'.$entrega.'",
                "'.$tipoOferta.'",
                "'.$valorOferta.'",
                "'.$imgOferta.'",
                "'.$productos[$i]["finOferta"].'",          
                "'.$acciones.'"    

        ],';
```

Gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Quítale las etiquetas html al texto con `strip_tags`.

```
<textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control input-lg descripcionProducto" placeholder="Ingresar descripción producto"><?php echo strip_tags($mi_descripcion);?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prodrias usar la función "**preg_replace**" para remover todos los saltos de linea y reemplazarlos por espacios;

```
 $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $textarea));
 echo $string;
```